# Java Axon migration from 2.4.2 version to 4.0.3

Tags: java, spring, axon

I'm trying to migrate an app that uses Axon framework v.2.4.2 jumping two major versions to 4.0.3.- possibly in 2 steps (2->3, 3->4).

The app also uses Spring.

Our application uses Axon in pretty simple way - just using Aggregates,  EventHandlers and @EventSourcingHandlers.

How do I go about doing it?

I've found the following post: [Is there any specific way for Axon migration from 2.4.3 version to 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124335/is-there-any-specific-way-for-axon-migration-from-2-4-3-version-to-3-1-1), 
and dribs and drabs of posts on the Axon forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/axonframework/upgrade%7Csort:date.

Sadly, most axon migration guides and documentation referenced in these sources is obsolete or have been removed.

Are there any migration guides still alive out there?
Also, which approach is better - migrating in one go or in two steps? 
Could someone with Axon experience please share their sources or insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the broken link in the the post you're referring to as the *migration help* from 2 to 3. I feel most of what's in there is still accurate, so would you mind specifying which bits in there do not map to your situation?

What I think is key in your situation is to ensure that your Axon-2 events will be able to cope with the new format which was introduced in Axon 3. More specifically, the addition of the `globalIndex`. Point 6 of the [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124335/is-there-any-specific-way-for-axon-migration-from-2-4-3-version-to-3-1-1) StackOverflow should still cover the solution to this.

What I can also point out is that the migration from 3 to 4 is a simpler one than from 2 to 3. The biggest changes which have been made between 3 and 4 is a thorough reordering of all our classes into different modules.
As such, I think jumping from 2 to 4 would be a doable thing.
If you want to have a look at the changes we made between 3 and 4, I'd like to refer you to [this](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/axon-4-api-changes.md) file. It contains all the changes which have been made when creating Axon 4.

So to summarize, I'd probably go for a direct jump from Axon 2 to 4, using the earlier mentioned 2-to-3 migration help and the 3-to-4 API changes document.
And, if you have any specific question regarding the migration, do not hesitate to update your question and ask for a follow from my part!

Comment: Thank you Steven! Much appreciated.